# Parsing an array with PHP in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want to parse an array with PHP's foreach loop to get the object names and values inside the 'ques' array.

```
[
{
"ques": [
    {
        "name": "comment",
        "value": "comment me for the reason",
        "sur_id": "1",
        "user_id": "admin@gmail.com",
        "pagename": "question_response"
    },
    {
        "name": "check-box[]",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "radio",
        "value": "radio 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "yes",
        "value": "no"
    }

]
"ques":[
{
        "name": "date",
        "value": "2015-10-23"
    },
    {
        "name": "select-deopdown",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "true",
        "value": "false"
    },
    {
        "name": "number",
        "value": "55"
    }
]
}
```

]

I want to separate the value from the 'ques' array:

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
   $content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
  // print_r($content);
  $content_value= mb_convert_encoding($content ,"UTF-8");
    $datas = json_decode($content, true);
     foreach($datas->ques as $values)
     {
         echo $values->value . "\n";
          print_r($values);
     }
   $test[] = array('ques' =>  $datas ,'answer'=>$values);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the desired array or output?

Comment: Note that `mysql_fetch_array` and its friends in the MySQL API have been deprecated for a long while and have been removed in PHP 7. If you're just learning, you'd better invest your time in PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Your input shows an array that contains one object, which contains two times the same property (ques). This is not possible. Please correct this, so we know what data you're actually dealing with.

Comment: table is created statically to show screen shot.